# Generating json file from table in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have data in the below form in table.

[image]

I want to generate data in the below format.

```
{
    "delete": [
        {
            "canonicalName": "TCS"          
        }
    ],
    "update": [
         {
            "canonicalName": "Wipro tech"
            "synonyms": [
                "Wipro technology"
            ]
         },
         {
            "canonicalName": "Infosys"
            "synonyms": [
                "Infosys tech"
            ]
         }
    ]       
    "add": [
        {
            "canonicalName": "Apple Computers",
            "synonyms": [
                "Apple"
            ]
        },
        {
            "canonicalName": "Google India",
            "synonyms": ["Google"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can write same in java using some libraries and POJO class. Is there any possibility I can create in Oracle PL/SQL? earlier I was reading data from jdbc and creating this file in java code. Now I have to keep this code as part of pl/sql procedure. Is there anyway i can generate data in the above format?

Comment: What's your oracle version? Is it >=12.2?

Comment: Suppose you have one more row, with ORGNAME = 'Apple Computers', SYNONYMS = 'Apple Inc', OPERATION = 'add'. What is the desired structure in that case? Will two distinct elements with canonicalName = 'Apple Computers' appear in the array for "add", each with exactly one synonym? Or will they be combined into a single element with canonicalName = 'Apple Computers', with all the synonyms collected into a single (possible multi-element) array of synonyms?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov yes it is 18c

Comment: Canonical name would be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output, when an organization only has a canonical name (no synonyms), you show the corresponding object with only one property, the canonical name. It would be easier if you allowed the `"synonyms"` property to exist in all cases - the corresponding array can be empty - but that is not what you show in your desired output.

If you allow empty arrays as the value of `"synonyms"` then Barbaros Ozhan provided the solution already.  **EDIT** Upon inspection, that may not be entirely true; the solution doesn't aggregate synonyms for a single organization into a single array (with two or more synonyms), showing them instead as distinct objects. See the sample data I added to my Answer, below. **END EDIT**

**MASSIVE EDITS HERE** I am adding sample data for testing. I assume that if an organization has two or more synonyms (under the same operation), that should result in a single member of the operation array (the canonical name appears only once, with an array of two or more synonyms).

I modified my solution too - found a simpler way. One can see the change to the solution by clicking on the "edited" link below the answer.

Test data:

```
drop table t purge;
create table t (orgname, synonyms, operation) as
  select 'Apple Computers', 'Apple'           , 'add'    from dual union all
  select 'Apple Computers', 'Apple Inc'       , 'add'    from dual union all
  select 'Google India'   , 'Google'          , 'add'    from dual union all
  select 'Wipro Tech'     , 'Wipro Technology', 'update' from dual union all
  select 'Infosys'        , 'Infosys Tech'    , 'update' from dual union all
  select 'TCS'            , null              , 'delete' from dual union all
  select 'IBM'            , null              , 'delete' from dual union all
  select 'IBM'            , 'IBM Corporation' , 'delete' from dual union all
  select 'IBM'            , 'IBM Corporation' , 'add'    from dual
;
```

Query:

```
with
  prep (operation, orgname, fragment) as (
    select operation, orgname,
           json_object( key 'canonicalName' value orgname,
                        key 'synonyms'
              value nullif(json_arrayagg(synonyms order by synonyms), '[]')
                                  FORMAT JSON  ABSENT ON NULL
                      )
     from   t
     group  by orgname, operation
   )
select json_objectagg( key operation
                       value json_arrayagg(fragment order by orgname)
                     ) as json_str
from   prep
group  by operation
;
```

Output (pretty printed):

```
{
  "add" :
  [
    {
      "canonicalName" : "Apple Computers",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "Apple",
    "Apple Inc"
      ]
    },
    {
      "canonicalName" : "Google India",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "Google"
      ]
    },
    {
      "canonicalName" : "IBM",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "IBM Corporation"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "delete" :
  [
    {
      "canonicalName" : "IBM",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "IBM Corporation"
      ]
    },
    {
      "canonicalName" : "TCS"
    }
  ],
  "update" :
  [
    {
      "canonicalName" : "Infosys",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "Infosys Tech"
      ]
    },
    {
      "canonicalName" : "Wipro Tech",
      "synonyms" :
      [
    "Wipro Technology"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much @mathguy for such an amazing answer. situation is there can be more than one synony and if synony is null we can remove synoym tab,

Comment: Hi @Mathguy I have extended my requirement little bit. your solution is perfect for me. Could you please help me to do changes please?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541003/creating-json-from-oracle-database-table

Answer (score 2):

If your DB version is `12cR2+`, then you can use `json_objectagg()`, `json_object()` and `json_array()` functions together as

```
SELECT json_query(
       json_objectagg
                 ( operation VALUE 
                   json_array(json_object('canonicalName' VALUE orgname,
                                          'synonyms'      VALUE json_array(synonyms) ) ) ),
       '$' returning VARCHAR2(4000) pretty )
    AS "Result JSON" 
  FROM tab
```

Don't forget to add `json_query( ... , '$' returning VARCHAR2(4000) pretty )` wrapping whole expression to get a nice appearance.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3cac91c3c597c31d3d3ea9fb10b906f)</kbd>

Comment: If my assumption (described below) is correct, then your solution doesn't quite do it. Namely: suppose that in the inputs, for the same "operation" and same "orgname", there are several synonyms. Then I *assume* (the OP needs to clarify) that the `"synonyms"` property must be a single array, aggregating all the synonyms for that organization. In your solution, the same `orgname` will appear multiple times under the same "operation".